# Calendar matrix - by momentjs and typescript

Tags: typescript, matrix, calendar, momentjs

[image]

Hello, if you need to create something like this - the day picker in calendar, look down at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This method gets year and month and returns matrix of [weeks][days] to build calendar view.

```
private getMonthCalendar(year: number, month: number) : Moment[][]
{
    const startDate: Moment = moment({ year: this.model.actualYear, month: this.model.actualMonth }).startOf('month');  //first day of month
    const endDay: Moment = moment(startDate).add(1, 'month').add(-1, 'day'); // last day of month

    // From first to last day of month, get index of all weeks to display
    const weeks: Dictionary<string, { week, year }> = new Dictionary();
    for (let day: Moment = moment(startDate); endDay.diff(day) >= 0; day.add(1, 'day'))
    {
        let key = day.isoWeekYear() + "_" + day.isoWeek();
        if (!weeks.containsKey(key))
        {
            weeks.setValue(key, { week: day.isoWeek(), year: day.isoWeekYear() });
        }
    }

    // lets build the calendar
    var calendar = [];
    weeks.forEach((index, week) =>
    {
        // Get seven days for every week
        var weekDays = [];
        for (var d = 1; d <= 7; d++)
        {
            weekDays.push(moment().isoWeekYear(week.year).isoWeek(week.week).day(d));
        }
        calendar.push(weekDays);
    });
    return calendar;
}
```